# Is Azure AD Multi tenant application for SharePoint possible?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, multi-tenancy, azure-ad

I'm trying to convert Provider Hosted SharePoint Online application to Azure AD multi-tenant app, but I'm having issues registering existing application on SharePoint.

I created new app on Azure AD where I get application ID and Secret. I try to use that ID and Secret in my SharePoint deployment process but I am unable to register SharePoint application with that ID.

Issue is similar with one shown in question:
[Can you create a multitenant provider hosted app without using the office store?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120957/can-you-create-a-multitenant-provider-hosted-app-without-using-the-office-store)
, however they reuse existing SharePoint ID & Secret but I cannot do that as Azure ID can only create new ID&Secret (meaning i cannot reuse existing one).

I need Azure AD app for OAuth flow because SharePoint app is used as office/outlook add-in, and only way to get user to log (and retrieve its info) in by using graph api.

Basically I'm grasping for straws here, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to either choose to use the appid/secret generated in SharePoint (appregnew.aspx) OR have the app being created in Azure AD. You can't combine this into the same app. SharePoint apps are still using the old Azure ACS (Access Control Services).

If you're using the Graph API, just use an Azure AD app, you can pass that auth token to the SharePoint endpoint as well, if you have the correct permissions set.

Comment: That makes sense. Further question then: I'm using Graph API to get access token for SharePoint and its working (requested permissions are granted and app principal is installed in AD of tenant owning the SharePoint site). The question is how do I use that app principal to create SharePoint app (or Office app, its confusing) which I will be able to run from office portal or even use as office/outlook addin. Hope its not too confusing

Comment: The thing is that you don't create a Sharepoint app, there's no point. Just an ordinary Web site/app with Azure AD Authentication

Comment: That would be ideal case, however I need the SharePoint app in order to add custom actions to SharePoint (custom actions on EditControlBlock, etc.). I'll try to just upload the SharePoint app with ClientID = Azure AD app ID and see how it goes. Hopefully it would bind the app principal generated by consent framework with the uploaded SharePoint App. Will keep you posted.

Comment: After further research I've found out that my use case requires 2 applications, one on Azure AD and one that is basically a SharePoint plugin. These two only work together as SharePoint plugin creates actions that point to Azure AD app.

Comment: @Spery Can you please more details on how you  implemented the authentication   as i have the same requirement.

Comment: Sorry, we've abandoned that approach. If I remembered correctly. They way we got it to work was by having out app defined on Azure AD as multi-tenant application, and add-ins on SharePoint would have their own id's (which were basically new Guids). Their ID's didnt really matter, as authorization to resources was done by Azure AD. You'd have to exchange authorization code for access tokens (one for SharePoint access, one for SharePoint admin access) and use them when creating SharePoint context. Hope it helps, tag me if you have more questions.